# configure master and slave with powerdns version 4.2

Tags: powerdns

Short description

I'm running two machines with PowerDNS, one being the master (SQL) and one being the slave (SQL). The problem is, that every domain added on master NS is not added on slave dns server

Environment

```
Operating system: CentOS7
Software version: powerdns4.2
```

Master's config ns1//192.168.1.99:

```
   daemon=yes
   guardian=no
   launch=gmysql
   gmysql-host=localhost
   gmysql-user=powerdns
   gmysql-password=mypassword
   gmysql-dbname=powerdns
   local-address=192.168.1.99
   local-port=53
   log-dns-details=yes
   log-dns-queries=yes
   log-timestamp=yes
   loglevel=4
   setgid=pdns
   setuid=pdns
   master=yes
   allow-axfr-ips=192.168.1.98
   also-notify=192.168.1.98


   daemon=yes
   guardian=no
   launch=gmysql
   gmysql-host=localhost
   gmysql-user=powerdns
   gmysql-password=mypassword
   gmysql-dbname=powerdns
   local-address=192.168.1.98
   local-port=53
   log-dns-details=yes
   log-dns-queries=yes
   log-timestamp=yes
   loglevel=4
   setgid=pdns
   setuid=pdns
   slave=yes
   master=no
   allow-notify-from=192.168.1.99



  master log:
  Mar 21 21:08:46 ns1 pdns_server: Unable to queue notification of domain              'exemple.com': nameservers do not resolve!
 Mar 21 21:08:46 ns1 pdns_server: Queued also-notification of domain' exemple.com' to 192.168.1.98:53
 Mar 21 21:08:48 ns1 pdns_server: Received unsuccessful notification    report for 'exemple.com' from 192.168.1.98:53, error: Query Refused
 Mar 21 21:08:48 ns1 pdns_server: Removed from notification list: 'exemple.com' to 192.168.1.98:53 Query Refused
```

PS same problem with firewall and selinux disabled
Please how can ensure the transfer of zones between master and slave ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Since 4.2 you need to add:

```
superslave=yes
```

to the slaves.

Link to the docs: https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/settings.html#superslave

Also make sure your supermaster table on the slaves is set up correctly with master data.